# Как передавать параметры в запрос API python

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Задача стоит следующая: ежедневно получать данные по API.
Исходя из документации запросы работают по следующей схеме:
Делаешь запрос на получение export_id.

Пример запроса:
https://{account_name}.getcourse.ru/pl/api/account/users?key={secret_key}&....
Вместо «....» добавляются необходимые параметры фильтра.

Параметры фильтра - Дата создания пользователей:

created_at[from]=YYYY-MM-DD

created_at[to]=YYYY-MM-DD

Т.к. мне необходимо выполнять запрос автоматически ежедневно, для получения актуальной даты я использую следующее решение:

```
import datetime as DT

today_str = DT.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

query = f"created_at[from]={today_str} created_at[to]={today_str}"
```

Целиком код выглядит вот так:

```
import requests 
import datetime as DT

today_str = DT.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
query = f"created_at[from]={today_str} created_at[to]={today_str}"

params = {'key1' : 'ZPlgNDj',
          'key2' : query}

response = requests.get ("https://{account_name}.getcourse.ru/pl/api/account/users?key=", params = params)
```

Помогите разобраться что не так

Comment: Откуда у вас взялись key1 и key2? В показанном вами примере запроса ничего такого нет.

Comment: key1 - это ключ для работы с api платформы
key2 - это фильтра который нужно добавить вместо ... в примере запроса

Comment: Вообще, не нужно мудрить, в соответствии с примером должно быть как-то так `params={'key': 'ZPlgNDj', 'created_at[from]': today_str, 'created_at[to]': today_str}` без всяких key1 и key2

Comment: Ну и `?key=` из ссылки стереть конечно, так как это мешает параметрам

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй так

```py
import requests 
import datetime as dt

account_name = "сюда_написать_аккаунт_нейм"
BASE_URL = f"https://{account_name}.getcourse.ru/pl/api/account/users"
today_str = dt.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


params = {'key' : 'ваш secret_key',
          'created_at[from]' : today_str,
          'created_at[to]': today_str}

response = requests.get(BASE_URL, params=params)
# Проверь потом правильно ли ссылка строится
print(response.request.url)
```